# Export function does not support .svg downloading

Tags: r, svg, shiny

I have the shiny app below which displays a `plotly()` oblect and a download button to download it. While png and jpeg are downloaded normally there seems to be an issue when I try to download the svg file.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(webshot)
ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("plot"),
  uiOutput("down")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  # renderPlotly() also understands ggplot2 objects!
  save<-reactive({
    plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~mpg, y = ~wt)

  })
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    save()
  })

  output$down<-renderUI({

    #Download files with quotes or not depending on the quote=input$quotes which has value TRUE or FALSE.
    output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {
        paste("test", "svg", sep = ".")
      },

      # This function should write data to a file given to it by
      # the argument 'file'.
      content = function(file) {
        # Write to a file specified by the 'file' argument
        export(save(), file=file)

      }

    )
    downloadButton("downloadData", "Download",class = "butt1")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you put the `switch` in there in the first place, but it looks very out of place to me.

As far as I know, `switch` is not a plotly- or shiny-function, but just the base-R function. And that function just helps you choose between cases, as a kind of help to prevent you from having to write endless if-else if-else if-...-statements.
It chooses from the 2nd to n-th argument based on the first, something like this:

```
myvar <- sample(c('one', 'two', 'three'))
counted <- switch(myvar,
                  one='First',
                  two='Second',
                  three='Third',
                  'Error')
```

The unnamed argument is there as a fallback, default value. *Syntactically* it's not wrong to give a default as the only value, but it does defeat the value. Basically, what you've written is `sep <- "jpeg"`, and then moved on, not using sep. You can check it by changing "jpeg" to something else, there is no difference.

In the next step, you're just trying to save your file, which *is* named correctly.
That causes export to try to save the plot in the format as recognised by the extension. Which can be done automatically for jpegs and pngs, but not for svg.

Some help is written in ?plotly::export, where it tells you it needs something from the RSelenium-package. Which unfortunately I can't help you with, but I think you can find answers by googling more of that package.
But the switch-line is misleading you, it's at least not working the way you are trying to use it.